# How to fetch a result from a triggered Action in order to yield return it in the containing method?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a parsing library that allows to pass an Action on getting data error (e.g. after reading a line).

Something like that below:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Parse(string fileName)
{
     // Initialize a parser reading the given fileName
     // ...
     myParser.Configuration.OnGettingDataError = (string error) => 
     {
          // Obviously we cannot yield return to the containing method above...
          yield return error;
     };
     while(myParser.Read())
     {
         yield return myParser.GetRecord();
     }
}
```

How can I can get the error yield returned from the containing method?
Is there a sort of pattern that I can apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to yield the error? You could however

- Store the error in a property/List, enumerate it after every `GetRecord`.
- Just `throw`, seems exceptional to me
- Or end enumeration and check for last error.

These are seemingly your only options

**Update**

Not entirely sure if this is what you are after, however...

```
public IEnumerable<string> Parse(string fileName)
{
   var errors = new List<string>();
   myParser.Configuration.OnGettingDataError = (string error) => errors.Add(error);

   while (myParser.Read())
   {
      yield return myParser.GetRecord();
      foreach(var error in errors)
         yield return error;
      errors.Clear();
   }
}
```

***Note*** : Totally untested, and a little suspect

Comment: Yeah I am sure, I also take it as a challenge in a more general context.